# scene taking to long to load at componentDidMount

Tags: react-native

In react native I tried to run long process in the componentDidMount:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const long= await new generateLongProcess();
    this.setState({ long });
  }
```

I am expecting the page to load before the long process run, but I am  facing a long pause from other page, before this page is loaded, and last the long is loaded.

Why this page takes few seconds to load? Because I thought all the component is loaded before running the long process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your componentDidMount function is an async function. And you have used await on new generateLongProcess();

So componentDidMount will wait until your generateLongProcess function finish. So, check that function. If you don't want to wait then just remove the 2 keywords async and await. But, if you need to get the long variables value then you have to wait or have to done that in Promise. It will be better if you show us the generateLongProcess function codes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what happens to the long process functions you use. But to guess why Lord is so long, it may be because of `SetState`. Because you are calling it from the '`componentDidMount`' function, `rendering` is done twice repeatedly.

> NOTE: In some cases, the `componentDidMount()` calls the `setState()`
>   immediately.In this case, the `render()` will be called twice, but the
>   user will not be able to see the intermediate course. This approach
>   can easily lead to performance issues and requires attention.

Comment: It is not because of the setState, I comment it out, problem remain.

Comment: Show me the function.